# What is the value of this DEFINEd constant?

Tags: android, c

I'm looking through some Android bluetooth source code, and I noticed these defines:

```
/* Non Connectable Adv state is supported. 0x0000000000000001 */
#define HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK          0x01
#define HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF           0
#define HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(x)      ((x)[HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF] & HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK)
```

The first 2 are quite obvious, but what is the value of the third one, and what does that (x) do?

Comment: x is an argument. that's a macro. essentially a compile-time "function". wherever you have HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(somevalue)`, the return value of that macro/function is what gets put into the compiled binary.

Comment: It is the bitwise `AND` of a specific element of the array you supplied as the *argument*, with a specific value. The element index and the `AND` operand are defined in the first two `#define`. So it is `((x)[0] & 1)`

Comment: `(x)` is in brackets to ensure that any qualifier passed as part of the expression `x` takes precedence over the indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most macros are simple text substitution, expanded where they occur in the code. So the third one

```
#define HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(x) ((x)[HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF] & HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK)
```

substitutes the two macros it contains, expanding to this:

```
((x)[0] & 0x01)
```

The `(x)` is in brackets to ensure that whatever argument is passed to the macro takes precedence over the indexing. So for example if the code is

```
char str[] = "123";
int i = HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(str + 1);
```

without the bracket around the argument `x` the macro would expand to

```
(str + 1[0] & 0x01)
```

which would cause a fault. The bracket makes it

```
((str + 1)[0] & 0x01)
```

and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the meaning of this piece of code is this.

if the Non Connectable Adv state is supported 
  than at offset HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF of the array that its
  structure is given by the user 
  with the parameter x (HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(x))
  the bit in place HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK will be with the value 1
Otherwise this bit will be with the value 0

In DSPs and in other processors that have similar (but not identical) processor versions. The difference in hardware is generally expressed by a macro as in the below example. We deliberately set different offsets and different masks to different processors.

A more rare use may be "calling" the macro with arrays of different types.
In the example below if TYPE1 is defined than we "call" the macro array of long integers as an argument. and if TYPE2 is defined than we "call" the macro with an array of short integers as an argument.

Both methods implement the macro as a kind of, primitive but fast virtual function.

```
//#define PROCESSOR1 or PROCESSOR2 
//#define TYPE1 or TYPE2

#ifdef PROCESSOR1
#define HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK          0x04
#define HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF           2
#define HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(x)      ((x)\
[HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF]\
& HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK)
#elif defined(PROCESSOR2)
#define HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK          0x01
#define HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF           0
#define HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(x)       ((x)\
[HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_OFF]\
 & HCI_SUPP_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_MASK)
#endif



#ifdef TYPE1
long Arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
#elif defined(TYPE2)
short Arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
#endif


int f()
{
    return(HCI_LE_STATES_NON_CONN_ADV_SUPPORTED(Arr));
}
```